# Open SSH mysql Workbench workaround

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I am trying to connect to mysql workbench, after I upgraded to newest version of Ubuntu which comes with OpenSSH 6.7.

I cannot tunnel into **mysql** using an SSH tunnel.
I can connect using `mysql -u root -p` with the same credentials i use in Workbench.

1. I have tried installing Paramiko 1.51.1 - No difference.
2. If I add `#KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp3$` line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` which fixes the problem BUT all my queries running in workbench timeout. This is not a viable solution.

Error that is thrown:

```
10:42:03 [INF][SH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one
10:42:03 [INF][SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to ..
10:42:03 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\sshtunnel.py", line 298, in _connect_ssh look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 301, in connect t.start_client()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 461, in start_client
raise e
SSHException: Incompatible ssh peer (no acceptable kex algorithm)
```

Is there a solution to this bug?

Answer (score 2):

You need to upgrade paramiko. Follow [this](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2015/03/paramiko-update-tutorial/) quide.

Comment: This answer is a bit old and when this is done on Windows it breaks the SSH Tunnel manager with the latest paramiko version: `Cannot start SSh tunnel manager`